# error al introducir una fecha en la base de datos con la función str_to_date

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy teniendo problemas al hacer una inserción con las función de SQL "str_to_date". Me dice que el campo fecha de nacimiento no puede ser nulo.

La consulta que estoy realizando es la siguiente

```
INSERT INTO Paciente VALUES(null,'aqwe','eqweqw','21312212',str_to_date('1993-04-20','%d/%m/%Y'), '23','Masculino', 'asdas','1','1','d','ABRITA CHICA','21695','','123','1231323','v@gmail.com',NOW());
```

El valor correspondiente a la fecha de nacimiento es tomado de un campo de tipo fecha

Dejo una captura, para que se entinda mejor

[image: Consulta sql]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el caracter de separacion de ser coma ","
ejemplo:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("1993,04,20 ", "%Y,%m,%d %h,%i,%s");
```

la forma mas sencilla seria

```
str_replace("-",",","1993-04-20");
```

Comment: Gracias, lo resolví de la siguiente forma `STR_TO_DATE('1993-04-20', '%Y-%m-%d')` creo que se debía a lo que me decías, el carácter de separación. Saludos.